# Laptop running hotter in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, windows, temperature

Specs: Dell Inspiron 7567, i7-7700hq, 4k resolution, Nvidia 1050Ti, 4GB Graphics Card,8GB Ram, 220GB SSD as primary drive(partitioned 60 GB for ubuntu and 70GB for Windows and rest space for files).
I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04LTS and Windows 10.

With Intel GPU and with Chrome(3 simple tabs), Discord open; Windows runs at 42°C to 48°C.
With Intel GPU, and with Chrome(1 Gmail tab) open); Ubuntu runs at 59°C to 64°C.

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu,(with Chrome and Psensors installed by me, rest came pre-installed).

Can't we get the same operating temperature range in Ubuntu as that of Windows? If yes, how can we achieve that?

Comment: But this is the operating temperature as reported by the respected operating systems?  You're not sticking a thermometer inside while it's running (I hope!).  As such, I wouldn't compare them directly and assume they would match exactly...  Does it "feel" warmer to you?  I mean when you touch the outside of the computer.

Comment: the fanning keeps on running fast to the point it is clearly audible, also yes the laptop feels a lot warmer and noisier. For temperature readings, I simply used programs. Core Temp for Windows and Psensor for Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you should change your goal to controlling the fan, instead of matching temperature values.  I don't know if these numbers are somehow read directly from BIOS or "something" is done to them so that you can't compare them directly.  As for your laptop getting warmer, perhaps you can take a look at what else is running in the background.  You might only have Chrome running, but behind it, other things might be running.  Maybe finding them out and uninstalling them will help.  Personally, "Ubuntu, with factory settings" is a bit meaningless since you can easily install other programs.